# /dev/sdc1: unable to read superblock

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, azure, sudo

Linux Ubuntu 14.04 (azure server)

I was trying to backup /dev/sda1 drive so I executed the

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdc1
```

command. While executing the command is available, the space was showing negative. I terminated the command. After that I was unable to open that drive so I ran this command.

```
sudo reboot
```

I have some important data on that disk. Now I cant see the mounted drive in my list `df -h`.

when I am trying to mount it.

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /datadrive
```

Then I get this output

```
sudo: unable to resolve host abc
mount: /dev/sdc1: can't read superblock
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Isn't your `/dev/sda1` partition OK after this?  What is it you find strange in a problem with a partially copied partition?  How can you check the available space of a partition that you're writing with `dd`?  Nothing adds up.

Comment: If you do `dd`, both drives should be _unmounted_, otherwise the mounted FSes will change data on either drive and you'll end up with a mishmash. Avail space means nothing while doing the dd. If sda1 is intact, repeat the dd [fully]. Also, ensure `sdc1` is large enough (i.e. do `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`). Why not use tar or rsync? Also, consider `ddrescue`

Answer (score 1):

If you did this

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdc1
```

and your data really was on sda1 then your data should still be safe on sda1.

Anything else and all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to backup the MBR too with `dd`, to restore after your disk cloning process, rewriting the partition table ( just to make sure ).

Copy the MBR :

```
~# dd if=<SOURCE_DISK> of=/path/to/mbr_file.img bs=512 count=1
```

Restore the partition table :

```
~# dd if=/path/to/mbr_file.img of=<DESTINATION_DISK> bs=1 skip=446 count=64
```

However, using `dd` for disk backup isn't the better choice for backup your Linux SO. When dealing with *NIX servers, the better approach is to use `tar` or `rsync` ( this one is the best for remote copy ), since you get more flexibility when changing the filesystem, disk size and partitioning scheme. I always use `rsync` to  deploy linux servers.

**NOTE**: For NTFS cloning I would recommend Partimage as tool.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some important data on that disk.

You mean the sdc1? If yes, there is not much hope of get the data back from it.

If the dd command has been executed, then the data on the head of the sdc1 will be overwritten. Super block is resides on the head of the file system. It may has been overwritten too. That's the reason why you get the error message when you try to mount the sdc1.

To recover as much as the data from sdc1, my thought is that restore the super block from its' backup.(There are copies of super block stored in the different place of the file system) And try to copy the files from the sdc1 when it is readable. Some files may be corrupt if they use the block reside on the head of the partition.(These blocks have been overwritten).

Here is a good [link](http://www.linfo.org/superblock) about super block.

Actually, I've gone through the same situation with you ever. I can't get anything restored in the end.

Besides, before performing any recover steps, please back the sdc1 with dd command to prevent the further damage.